# Animation Not Proper starting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

i do clock animation it works well but i use setinterval to call the function. the animation has little delay while start[ it stops some time on 12]

```
var timemin=0;
var timehr=0;
var timesec=0;
var a=0;
function clockRotate(){
timemin=timemin+6;
timehr=timehr+0.5;
timesec=timesec+360;
$("#cimg3").animate({rotate:timemin},2500);
$("#cimg4").animate({rotate:timesec},2500);
$("#cimg2").animate({rotate:timehr},2500);
}

setInterval(function(){
clockRotate();
a=1;
},0*2500);
```

[**See The Action Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wf6kn/1/)

How can i remove This delay. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `"linear"`. By default it is "swing" which makes the animation slower at the beginning and the end. [Animate Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
var timemin=0;
var timehr=0;
var timesec=0;
var a=0;
function clockRotate(){
    timemin=timemin+6;
    timehr=timehr+0.5;
    timesec=timesec+360;
    $("#cimg3").animate({rotate:timemin},2500,"linear");
    $("#cimg4").animate({rotate:timesec},2500,"linear");
    $("#cimg2").animate({rotate:timehr},2500,"linear");
}

setInterval(function(){
    clockRotate();
    a=1;
}, 0*2500);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wf6kn/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking the easing property:

take at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wf6kn/18/)

```
$("#cimg3").animate({
  rotate: timemin
}, {
  easing: "linear"
}, 2500);
```